# Submitting Java App Using Install4j to Apple Store

Tags: java, install4j, mac-app-store

We are also trying to package our Java application for the Apple store. We are glad that install4j now supports bundling the OpenJDK, signing and entitlements for sandboxing. 
However, the installer output formats are either a dmg or tgz for Mac OSX media files. But App Loader (Apple's app to submit binaries to the store) expects a .pkg file.

So how do we easily go from the install4j output to a pkg file while still keeping signing information, entitlements, etc...

Most instructions on the Apple store are targeted to Apple developers. There are also other options and it is hard to know what route to take. Apparently XCode can also submit to the Apple store but it seems to work with code directly. Finally there is also Package Maker.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I found this link:  

http://intransitione.com/blog/take-java-to-app-store/

but before jumping on creating our own installer, I would like to know if other java developers have found an easier way, using Install4j.